# Use groovy categories to add dynamic properties

Tags: groovy, metaclass

Expanding on [this blog post](http://joesgroovyblog.blogspot.com/2007/09/and-miles-to-go-before-i-sleep.html), I am trying to use a category to create a simple DSL for use with the `javax.measure` (JSR-275) classes (similar to TimeCategory for time intervals)

However, I do not want to add boilerplate code for each of the possible available methods (getMeter, getMilliMeter, getKelvin, getSecond etc.). I thought overriding the `getProperty(String)` method would work, but alas, it looks like the `getProperty` method defined in the category is not used when accessing the property directly.

Here is some simplified code to demonstrate:
    import javax.measure.quantity.Length;
    import javax.measure.unit.Unit;
    import javax.measure.Measure;

```
@Category(Number)
class LengthCategory {      
    public Measure<BigDecimal, Length> getProperty(String unit){
        return Measure.valueOf(this,Unit.valueOf(unit));
    }
}

use(LengthCategory){
    println 3.getProperty("m")  // this works
    println 3.m                 // this reports a non-exisiting property
    prinlln 3.'m'               // as does this
}
```

Assuming other methods of dynamically adding properties to a runtime object (e.g. `Expando`, subclassing `GroovyInterceptible`, mixins and other metaclass manipulations) is not viable and I would really rather not have to manually code getters for every possible unit and SI prefix combination. There are obviously other ways to go about creating a DSL for measurements, but I would still like to understand why this method would not work.

Could someone explain why the `getProperty` method of the category does not override `.propertyName` usage? I am obviously missing something important about the resolution of property names using the metaclass during runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why `getProperty` doesn't work on categories. But you can define a `get` method on them that does basically the same (i think). This works:

```
@Category(Number)
class LengthCategory {      
    def get(String unit) {
        "$this $unit"
    }
}

use (LengthCategory) {
    println 3.m   // 3 m
    println 3.'m' // 3 m
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I want, but I would still like to know Why the implementing getProperty(String name) in the category does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't actually extend Integers with full (i.e., readable and writable) properties using Category -- only with methods.

You can extend an Integer using read-only properties by using the method version of the property. You can even make it writable by including a set method. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to store the value passed in other than in a static variable and that ends up affecting all Integers.

Example:

```
$ cat catprop
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy

@Category(Integer)
class CatInteger {
  private static String str = "default"
  public static String setN(Integer i, String _str) { str = _str }
  public static String getN(Integer i) { return str }
}

use (CatInteger) {
  3.n = "333a"
  println "3.n is " + 3.n

  3.n = "333b"
  println "3.n is " + 3.n

  4.n = "444"
  println "4.n is " + 4.n
  println "3.n is " + 3.n
}
$ catprop
3.n is 333a
3.n is 333b
4.n is 444
3.n is 444
$
```

Note that in the last line 3.n return "444" because the stored field is static. I suppose that one could use a private HashMap and store a value for every Integer accessed, but that's too ugly to contemplate.

Another possibility would be to use the MetaClass Interface's getProperty() and setProperty(). However, I haven't looked into that so I don't know if it would work or not (just a thought).

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer, but not sure, if you's still want to use JSR-275 now that [JSR-363](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=363) is final?;-)

Comment: Good point, but this is a rather old question. The new JSR hat not been ratified when originally asked.

Comment: That's correct. It was refering to the latest example/answer, not sure why it ended up above it? We do offer Groovy support for JSR 363 under https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-spaces/tree/master/groovy-space. Similar to what was done for JSR 354 (JavaMoney) before.